# Allow user to upload image through HTML form - Django

Tags: python, django

I am  creating a donation web application. I want the user to be able to upload a picture of the item they are donating, and for it to save to my database. This works if I do it through the admin panel, but I can't figure out how to do it with an html form. Thank you to everyone who helps. My code is down bellow.

---

**Image upload (this is the part of the form that allows the user to upload an image):**

```
<label class="label-input100" for="image">Image*</label>
                <div class="">
                    <input id="image" class="input100" type="file" name="image"  required>
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
```

**Donation View (I take a lot of data from other parts of the form, and save it to the model. I haven't added any code to save the image yet, i'm not sure how to do that.**

```
def donate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST['donationtitle']
        phonenumber = request.POST['phonenumber']
        category = request.POST['category']
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        location = request.POST['location']
        description = request.POST['description']
        date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
        ins = Donation(title = title, phonenumber = phonenumber, category = category, quantity = quantity, location = location, description = description, user=request.user, date = date )
        ins.save()
        # New part. Update donor's stats.
        UserDetail.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(donations=F('donations') + 1)
        UserDetail.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(points=F('points') + (quantity * 2))
        return HttpResponseRedirect( '/thankyou/', )
    return render(request,'donate.html')
```

**Donation Model: (I have the image field here, and it works when I upload through my admin panel)**

```
class Donation(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=12)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  quantity  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,)
  image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True, upload_to = 'images/')       
  description = models.TextField()
  date = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=999)
  user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
  @property
  def imageURL(self):
    try:
      url = self.image.url
    except: 
      url = 'images/gooddeedplaceholderimage.png'
    return url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just work if you add one line

```
ins.image=request.FILES['image']
```

before the ins.save() line

Comment: Wow! So easy. Thank you.